# How to pass dates(yyyy-MM-dd) falling only for weekdays in Jmeter

Tags: java, json, jmeter-5.0

I need to pass date parameter in the json payload which can validate that it should be weekday only.

```
 {
     "name": "PICKUP_DATE",
     "value": "${__timeShift(yyyy-MM-dd,,P1D,,)}"
 }
```

is there any time function with the said condition that can be used here ? please help !

Answer (score 2):

```
    Set<DayOfWeek> weekdays = EnumSet.range(DayOfWeek.MONDAY, DayOfWeek.SATURDAY);
    
    LocalDate sampleDate = LocalDate.of(2021, Month.FEBRUARY, 7);
    DayOfWeek dow = sampleDate.getDayOfWeek();
    if (weekdays.contains(dow)) {
        System.out.format("%s is a weekday, it’s a %tA%n", sampleDate, dow);
    } else {
        System.out.format("%s is a %tA, so not a weekday%n", sampleDate, dow);
    }
```

Output in US locale is:

> 2021-02-07 is a Sunday, so not a weekday

`EnumSet.range()` is unusual in that both endpoints are inclusive. So in my code above I have included Saturday as a weekday. You can change the set to contain exactly the weekdays you want in your situation.

### Link

[Oracle tutorial: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/) explaining how to use java.time, the modern Java date and time API.